# Terminal output to printer and not to monitor

Tags: printing

Suppose I don't want to use monitors with my Raspberry Pi. All terminal output should be printed on paper, and all the user inputs should be printed on paper. Something like a typewriter, but one that is interactive.

What kind of software should I install to achieve this functionality? What hardware would be needed (e.g. type of printer)?

Comment: I'd go with one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33 <- Includes a keyboard!

Comment: @goldilocks Ah but its not very practical to use antiques on a daily basis. Not very easily reproducible by others when using antiques. Anything that I can build out of Raspberry Pi + other modern components?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it matters what type of printer it is as long as it supported under linux (or whatever OS you intend to use).

Comment: @goldilocks My HP printer, for example, only seems to print entire A4 pages at once, and not line by line as required.

Comment: You could investigate that one at http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @goldilocks I was thinking of suggesting an ASR33, but thought I would be flagged for excessive sarcasm. The very first thing I designed (~1975) was a screen, so I didn't waste paper!

Comment: Asked on the Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange site: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/recommendations-for-modern-teletypewriters